# Как часто надо делать комит?

Tags: контроль-версий

когда заканчивается проект? на каждой задаче, либо раз в месяц?)

Comment: на каждой задаче

Answer (score 3):

Коммиты не должны быть привязаны ко времени. К задачам тоже не верно. Желательно привязывать к фичам/работающему функционалу.

Если речь про git, то рекомендую:

1. На каждую задачу создавать новую ветку.
2. Коммитить функционал по готовности. Как можно детерминированней.

Не надо, безусловно, коммитить отдельно каждую функцию. Но, если выбирать между этим и заливкой всех изменений одним коммитом, то лучше первое.

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от требований тим лидера или заказчика. Если ты себе сеньёр, сам тим лидер и заказчик то сам и решай как часто делать. Можно использовать гит как репозиторий для хранения, тогда коммиты будут делаться редко. При коммите каждой задачи это будет выглядеть:

`git commit -am"пофиксил задание №777"`.

Лично я люблю коммитить после успешного завершения задачи, то есть полность рабочая кнопка на сайте. Или полность рабочий интерфейс. Бывает что нужно сделать просто страховочный коммит и отправить на репу чтобы код не пропал в случае если жесткий диск накроется например (или твой ноутбук случайно выбросят в окно). Также если нашлись баги то можно писать коммит на каждый баг и писать в описание что мы там пофиксили. А еще можно писать коммиты после написания класса или функции а также написания скрипта. Рекомендую работать с гит через командную строку (терминал на линукс). А если нужно просмотреть код, то использовать прогу визуальный редактор для гит типа ГитКракен или любую другую. Также рекомендую битбакет.

Answer (score 0):

На каждой задаче. Иногда на каждой подзадаче, я каждый час иногда делаю.